# What is the risk of directly accessing /var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume_name> data?

Tags: docker, docker-volumes

Over the years I have been using docker for self-hosting, I never really cared about mounted volumes because I did not see real advantages vs mounted folders (I know about advantages related to permissions, etc. but that has not been a deal breaker for me).

Only recently, I discovered that a docker volume can be accessed through `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume_name>` (on Arch). This led me to the question: **why bother with mounted directories then, since the volume data is available through the directory above?**

This is the exact opposite of the approach I had so far. Still, if the volume contents are readily available, all the concerns I could have had (editing files, backup, ...) are gone, with all the goodness of volumes as an added value (especially the fact that I do not need to bother maintaining a `/etc/docker/<service>` tree).

Since this sounds too good to be true - I would like to understand the drawbacks of directly accessing volume data through `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume_name>` (accessing from the system/OS/shell, not from docker itself).

Comment: tbh I cheated with that way my certificates with a symlink, but I never had any issues with that

Answer (score 0):

While in general I'd say it's mostly safe (both a named volume and an explicit bind mount are essentially the same), here are some things to consider:

- **Reading files** - very safe, since you're not changing anything
- **Different UID/GID** - You have the same issue with a typical bind mount, but the UID and GID of files have a different assignment inside the container. That means if you mess up file permissions on the host side, the services inside the container might not be able to access the files.
- **Access to `/var/lib/docker/volumes`** - A non-root user cannot access `/var/lib/docker/volumes`, while that same user could access a directory elsewhere that is bind mounted.
- **Existing directories** - Sometimes you want to mount an existing directory on the host versus copying it to a volume, such as one that should be shared between the host and the container.
- **Single file mounts** - Somewhat related, but single file mounts (e.g. `-v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts`) can't use named volumes, obviously.

I'm not familiar with the `/etc/docker/<service>` tree (maybe that's an Arch thing?).